# Querying Empty Table Terminates Ruby Program

Tags: sql, ruby, sql-server

I have a simple method which queries a Sql-Server database's table using a Stored procedure in Ruby language.

```
@app_config = YAML.load_file("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../config/sa.gw.c.victim.yml")
connection_manager = ConnectionManager.new(@app_config["tpaldb"]) #H
 begin        
    sql = "exec spTPal_Vic_GetDeviceStateByIMEI '000000000000000'"
    result = connection_manager.execute_sproc(sql)
          result.each {|r| 
          #puts "#{r['DeviceID']} #{r['UniqueID']} #{r['DeviceType']}"
          puts r['DeviceID']           
          }
    connection_manager.connection.close()
     rescue => e
      puts "An error occurred while getting the device info for victimdevice_IMEI  #{victimdevice_IMEI} detail: #{e.message}"  

    end
```

Now the table is empty. When result = connection_manager.execute_sproc(sql) code excutes the ruby program terminates silently with identifying me about anything.
What I want is to know that query returned an empty result result on the front end instead of changing the stored procedure to say return null or anything else.
What is the way in ruby to identify that query or SP returned empty result.
Thank You.

Comment: Could you try to provided the parameter name,too? For example - `exec spTPal_Vic_GetDeviceStateByIMEI @myparametername='000000000000000'`

Comment: Trying parameter exec spTPal_Vic_GetDeviceStateByIMEI @myparametername='000000000000000' in the code doesn't work out. Still the program terminates silently.

Comment: So, if you execute the `exec spTPal_Vic_GetDeviceStateByIMEI '000000000000000'`statement in the Management Studio an empty result set is return?

Comment: Yes i know that nothing is present in the table right now but why does ruby code terminates with let me know what came back from database query.

Comment: Could you paste the error massage?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see, that seems like the correct behavior.  You run a query which you expect to return nothing.  You then iterate over the (empty) results and....  nothing happens.  Try checking `result.count` or whatever the appropriate method is to get the size of your result set - I'm not familiar with the object returned by ConnectionManager.  But a query that returns no rows is not in and of itself an error.